# PHP DOMDocument change node class instances while cloning/return?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I managed to use PHP DOM implementation to create my custom document tree containing subclasses of `DOMElement`s but I found something very strange: Cloning or returning a DOMDocument seems to change child node classes.

Basic example

```
class Section extends DOMElement
{
  public function __construct($name, $value = null, $uri = null)
  {
    parent::__construct($name, $value, $uri);
  }
}

class Paragraph extends DOMElement
{
  public function __construct($name, $value = null, $uri = null)
  {
    parent::__construct($name, $value, $uri);
  }
}

function display_doc($label, DOMDocument $doc)
{
  $endl = (PHP_SAPI == "cli") ? "\n" : "&lt;br /&gt;";
  $pad  = (PHP_SAPI == "cli") ? "\t" : "&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;";
  echo ($label . $endl);

  $root = $doc->documentElement;
  echo ($pad . "root " . get_class($root) . $endl);
  echo ($pad . "first child " . get_class($root->firstChild) . $endl);
}

function test_dom($name, DOMDocument &$instance = null)
{
  $doc = ($instance) ? $instance : new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
  $root = $doc->appendChild($doc->createElement("root"));
  $section = new Section("section");

  $root->appendChild($section);
  $paragraph = new Paragraph("para");
  $section->appendChild($paragraph);

  $clone = clone $doc;

  display_doc($name . " - Inside function", $doc);
  display_doc($name . " - Inside function (clone)", $clone);

  return $doc;
}

$doc = test_dom("Using new instance");
display_doc("Returned doc in global scope", $doc);

$doc2 = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
test_dom("Using global scope instance", $doc2);
display_doc("Modified doc in global scope", $doc2);
```

Will output

```
Using new instance - Inside function
    root DOMElement
    first child Section
Using new instance - Inside function (clone)
    root DOMElement
    first child DOMElement
Returned doc in global scope
    root DOMElement
    first child DOMElement
Using global scope instance - Inside function
    root DOMElement
    first child Section
Using global scope instance - Inside function (clone)
    root DOMElement
    first child DOMElement
Modified doc in global scope
    root DOMElement
    first child DOMElement
```

The class of the first child changes from `Section` to a simple `DOMElement` when the document is cloned or returned (even by reference)

- My PHP version is 5.3.10 but the same behavior occurs under 5.4
- using DOMDocument::registerNodeClass will transform `DOMElement` by the registered node class but I have more than one subclass of `DOMElement`

My question is not really about finding a workaround or a different solution but I'd like to understand what's happening here and by which mechanism the child nodes are transformed.

Edit: I found a bug report (2 years old) related to this issue: http://www.mail-archive.com/php-bugs@lists.php.net/msg134710.html.
The proposed workaround work well but it is stil unclear if it's a real bug or a invalid use of the DOM API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `new Paragraph` and `new Section` you will need to store them in a separate array to keep them in memory, so that `DOMDocument` doesn't just use it's default class.

The bug report is accurate, and it's my opinion that the entire implementation of `DOM` in PHP is flawed.

Keeping a copy of the object elsewhere is memory intensive, as is using DOM anyway. I am struggling personally to get a decent implementation to work because of the many flaws, so you're not the only one :)